# Installed PHP on CentOS, some features not working

Tags: centos, php.ini

I followed this guide to install PHP 5.3 on my CentOS 5 server:
http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/

I have phpMyAdmin extracted in a directory but it says it can't find the mysql extension. Moreover, I know I'll need the mysqli extension for other programs such as Drupal. The guide I followed says that those extensions come with it. When I run php -m it shows both mysql and mysqli though - that's where I'm puzzled.

I restarted apache and still no go. Where do you think my next step is?

phpinfo say my ini is in /etc/php.ini - should I be looking in there for something?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Post the Apache's error_log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have phpMyAdmin extracted in a directory but it says it can't find
>   the mysql extension.

Make sure that `php-mysql` is installed:

```
# yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php-mysql
```

Don't forget to restart the Apache after that.

Comment: did an rpm -qa and it shows php-mysql-5.3.8-1.w5 installed. I checked to see if they, mysqli and mysql, were enabled in /etc/php.d and they are. Still no luck though.

Comment: When I do the php -m, it shows the packages at the bottom under [PHP Modules] - but at the top it says PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'path to .so' ... it has this error for mysqli.so and mysql.so

Comment: Does it exist in `/usr/lib(64)/php/modules`? Did you try to reinstall php-mysql?

Comment: They are all in /usr/lib/php/modules/ - but when I cat them, it is just scrambed code. I couldn't cd to /usr/lib(64)/php/modules ... it gave me a syntax error. 

I didn't reinstall. I yum removed php-* and installed fresh following that guide. The only thing I added was the install php-mysql line you have in your answer. Everything should be fresh, I had php 5.0 on the server before, but I removed that with yum. Thanks for your help so far, I am so confused at this.

Comment: I just realized that the warnings are saying this directory:

PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/*.so'

If I change those without the /no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ - which has only apc.so and memcache.so, to /usr/lib/php/modules - will that fix my problem? How can I tell php to point there? Am I on the right track or are these directories for different things?

Comment: UPDATE: I simply cp'ed all *.so in /usr/lib/php/modules/ to /usr/local/lib/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ and everything seems to be working. phpMyAdmin loaded mysql extension. Is there anything to worry about with this fix? I'm marking this question as answered. Thanks, quanta. Apparently this is a bug in php 5.3 I read.

Comment: `grep extension_dir /etc/php.ini`?

Comment: it says "; extension_dir directove above." - there is nothing above.

Comment: What does it say on the `phpinfo()` page? I bet it is `/usr/local/lib/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613`.

Comment: Yep! That's where it is. No big deal I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/php.d for mysql.ini and mysqli.ini as well

Comment: They are both there, they are both enabled. Still no luck though. Thanks for the reply.